# Redirect does not occur if trailing slash exists

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https, apache2

I have the following lines in my `.htaccess` file in a directory called **blog**.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Different things happen when I do the following:

```
https://staging.example.com/blog/ - redirect does not work
https://staging.example.com/blog - redirect does work
```

When a trailing slash exists my redirect does not work, why is that the case?

**Update**

This is the blog/.htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# Froce HTTP
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `https://staging.example.com/blog/ - redirect does not work`

This could be due a presence of `blog/.htaccess`. If that is true then add this line on top of other rules there as well:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} https
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I do have a .htaccess file and it does include `RewriteEngine On`. Any other ideas?

Comment: That is indeed the problem. Include above rule just below RewriteEngine line.

Comment: I have updated my question to show my .htaccess file. I do have that rule right underneath `RewriteEngine On`. Maybe I am misunderstanding what you mean?

Comment: Try placing it just below `RewriteBase /blog/` line.

Comment: Also if `/blog/` is being served by WP then change BLOG URL to `http://` in it's permalink settings as well.

Comment: I've tried both of those suggestions previously and it didn't work. Do you think this issue may be related to the fact that my SSL certificate is on an AWS ELB? I can't see how.

Comment: No that shouldn't affect, but is it a WP site?

Comment: Also run `https://staging.example.com/blog/` in Firebug and see what you get in `Net tab`.

Comment: I've had a look at the net tab and console log and the only complaints are about SSL issues. I've set apache log level to debug and nothing really shows up.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42344/discussion-between-anubhava-and-abs)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a catalog with name equal to the redirect "path", it has more priority than your rule.

In your case, if you have a "blog" directory under DocumentRoot, redirecting simply fails.

We need more informaction about your structure and other rules.

But I've not been sleeping for a bunch of nights because of existing directory which prevented my rewriting rules.